# Find the PDF of the CDF of a normal random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

i have a random variable c=standard normal 
G is another random variable where G= the cdf of C 
what's the pdf of G ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE - please look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on how to format a question on this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CDF of any support-$\Bbb R$ continuous random variable has a $U(0,\,1)$ distribution, with constant pdf $1$ on $[0,\,1]$.